# Redisgraph find shortest path between 2 nodes

Tags: java, redis, redisgraph

I am new to using graph tech . Below is one sample data i have , i want to put this in redis graph and find the shortest distance between 2 points .

{"Entry":{"Reception":152},"Reception":{"Corner":176,"Exit":153},"Corner":{"Gate":41,"Reception":176},"Gate":{"LiftLobby":53,"Corner":41},"LiftLobby":{"Gate":53}}

For example in this json object distance between Entry and Reception point is 152 units .
What are the redisgraph queries i should use  to

1. Add data to the redisgraph.
2. To Find shortest distance between 2 points .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, that's how I would model this data in RedisGraph:

- Create `Loc` entities with `name` property: Entry, Reception, Corner, Exit, Gate, LiftLoby
- Create `Way` relationships between pairs of entities with `dist` property

To find the shortest path between two places - use RedisGraph 2.10 `algo.SPpaths` procedure (see "Single-Pair minimal-weight bounded-cost bounded-length paths" [here](https://redis.io/commands/graph.query/)).

Creating the graph:

```
GRAPH.QUERY g "CREATE (e:Loc{name:'Entry'}), (r:Loc{name:'Reception'}), (c:Loc{name:'Corner'}), (x:Loc{name:'Exit'}), (g:Loc{name:'Gate'}), (l:Loc{name:'LiftLobby'}), (e)-[:Way{dist:152}]->(r), (r)-[:Way{dist:176}]->(c), (r)-[:Way{dist:153}]->(x), (c)-[:Way{dist:41}]->(g), (c)-[:Way{dist:176}]->(r), (g)-[:Way{dist:53}]->(l), (g)-[:Way{dist:41}]->(c), (l)-[:Way{dist:53}]->(g)"
1) 1) "Labels added: 1"
   2) "Nodes created: 6"
   3) "Properties set: 14"
   4) "Relationships created: 8"
   5) "Cached execution: 0"
   6) "Query internal execution time: 0.788600 milliseconds"
```

Querying for the shortest path between Entry and Gate:

```
GRAPH.QUERY g "MATCH (e:Loc{name:'Entry'}), (g:Loc{name:'Gate'}) CALL algo.SPpaths( {sourceNode: e, targetNode: g, relTypes: ['Way'], weightProp: 'dist'} ) YIELD path, pathWeight RETURN pathWeight, [n in nodes(path) | n.name] as pathNodes ORDER BY pathWeight"
1) 1) "pathWeight"
   2) "pathNodes"
2) 1) 1) "369"
      2) "[Entry, Reception, Corner, Gate]"
3) 1) "Cached execution: 0"
   2) "Query internal execution time: 0.540100 milliseconds"
```

Comment: Thanks Lior , i am running redisgraph using docker run -p 6379:6379 -it --rm redislabs/redisgraph , docker is showing the latest version . But not sure why it is showing "Procedure `algo.SPpaths` is not registered"

Comment: RedisGraph 2.10 will be released next month. `latest` is currently 2.8.19 and it does not include this algorithm. For now, please use the `edge` version: `docker pull redislabs/redisgraph:edge`

Comment: Thanks very much , appreciate your help .